# How to make variable values persistent between function calls in c / c++

Tags: c++, c

I have the following szenario.
I am calling functions in a DLL from a IBM Notes application (Lotusscript).

One of the functions uses type structures and we encounter problems on 64Bit.
All values in the TYPE can only be passed to the function ByRef, but I need to pass the values ByVal.

So I decided to have single arguments in the function header for every value. So far, so good. I have around 43 arguments, but LS can only handle 31 ...

Next idea was to call i.e INIT_REG_PERSON_INFO(arg1,arg2, ... ) before I make a call to the function that registers a new user.

```
INIT_REG_PERSON_INFO(arg1,arg2, ... );
INIT_REG_ID_INFO(arg1,arg2, ... );
REGISTER_USER();
```

In C, I have a function ( I know, only one argument, but it is only for testing )

```
    /*====================================================================================*/
    /* FUNCTION: BCC_InitRegPersonInfo                                                    */
    /*====================================================================================*/
    STATUS LNPUBLIC BCC_InitRegPersonInfo(char *FirstName){
        try {
            //extern char *REG_PERSON_INFO_FIRSTNAME;
            memset(&reg_person_info, 0, sizeof (reg_person_info));
            reg_person_info.FirstName = FirstName;

            return NOERROR;

        } catch (...)    {
            LogEventText("* BCC_InitRegPersonInfo::Exception *", NULLHANDLE, NOERROR);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

whre reg_person_info is declared as a global variable

```
REG_PERSON_INFO reg_person_info;
```

Later, in my REGISTER_USER(), I try to access the value from the global variable

```
LogEventText("* BCC_RegNewPerson1():reg_person_info.FirstName = %s", NULLHANDLE, NOERROR,
                    reg_person_info.FirstName);
```

But the value is always empty. I assume, the variable is deleted / reset, as soon as I exit INIT_REG_PERSON_INFO(arg1,arg2, ... );

How would I make the value persistent between function calls?

Comment: Where did you originally declare `reg_person_info`? Could you post that bit of code/file?

Comment: your "C" function is obvioiusly not C but C++.

Comment: If this is really a global variable and you don't play games with loading and unloading of shared libraries, the value must be persistent during the same run of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `extern`al linkage for `reg_person_info` structure. In this way you are implicitly saying "I want this to be available to all units who declares it, including the main declaration unit".

In the begininning of the file where you have:

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC BCC_InitRegPersonInfo(char *FirstName){...}
```

Simply put `extern typeOfReg_Person_Info reg_person_info;`

by the looks of your code snippet, I am assuming that you have declared `reg_person_info` somewhere in a header file and `#include` the header file where you need? I'll update my answer once I have seen more code in the question.

Comment: Yes, I have declared  extern REG_PERSON_INFO reg_person_info; in the header. All functions exist in the same .cpp file using this header file.

Unfortunately,when linking, I get the following error

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol reg_person_info

Comment: @UlrichKrause      but you need declare it in your header file first (without extern) - and then declare it again in your .cpp file(s) (with `extern` keyword). This enables the external linkage and makes sure that any change made by one of the functions is visible globally

Comment: >>  and then declare it again in your .cpp file(s) with extern keyword

that does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A practice I have seen and used often to share global variables among units is:

```
/* globals.h */
#ifndef EXTERN
#define EXTERN extern
#endif

EXTERN int gMyGloablVar;

/* some-other-C-file */
#include "globals.h"

/* main.c */
#define EXTERN
#include "globals.h"
```

In main.c the storage is allocated; in all other compilation units they variables are declared as extern and so are known. In link time the linker fixes all references to the variables in main.